# Permission required for create aws backup vault

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-backup

```
TableBackupVault:
    Type: AWS::Backup::BackupVault
    Properties:
      BackupVaultName: tabel-vault
```

What permission are required for creating backup vault?

I tried these

```
          - Sid: Backup
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - backup:CreateBackupVault
              - backup:CreateBackupPlan
              - backup:CreateBackupSelection
              - backup:TagResource
              - backup:UntagResource
            Resource:
              - *
```

But I am getting

```
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: BackupVault (AWS::Backup::BackupVault)
Resource handler returned message: "Insufficient privileges to perform this action"
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this error, you have to add the following iam rule additionnaly:

```
backup-storage:MountCapsule
```

As it is required here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/access-control.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33416768)